# According to Advaita philosophy, is the Absolute Brahman formless?

Tags: brahman, advaita

In [Kena Upanishad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad/d/doc122448.html) following has been said about the Absolute:

> ‘What sight fails to see, but what sees sight— know thou That
>   alone as Brahman, and not this that people worship here.’

As per my understanding the meaning of the above is that Brahman is formless. Because if Brahman had any form(material or spiritual) then sight would have seen it.

So my question is: Is the Absolute Brahman formless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Brahman is formless.

Astavakra Samhita:

> I.5 - You do not belong to the Brahmana or any other caste or to any ashrama. You
>   are not perceived by the senses. Unattached, formless and witness of all are you. Be
>   happy.
>
> I.17 -  **You are unconditioned, immutable, formless**, of cool disposition, of
>   unfathomable intelligence and unperturbed. Desire Consciousness alone.
>
> I.18 - Know that which has form to be unreal and the formless to be permanent.
>   Through this spiritual instruction you will escape the possibility of rebirth
>
> VII.3 - In me, the boundless ocean, is the imagination of the universe. **I am quite tranquil and formless.** In this alone do I abide.
>
> XVIII.57 - The sense of duty, indeed, is the world of relativity. It is transcended by the
>   wise who realizes himself as all-pervasive, formless, immutable, and untainted.